# Parsing string literals in Prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am using definite clause grammars to parse string literals in Prolog, but this grammar rule can only parse string literals that contain alphabetic characters:

```
string_literal(S) --> "\"", symbol(S), "\"".
symbol([L|Ls]) --> letter(L), symbol_r(Ls).
symbol_r([L|Ls]) --> letter(L), symbol_r(Ls).
symbol_r([])     --> [].
letter(Let)     --> [Let], { code_type(Let, alpha) }.
```

Is it possible to write a DCG rule that can parse string literals with other types of symbols?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, library([dcg/basics](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl)) has several ready to use non terminals. The code is worth to study...

Otherwise, to generalize a bit you could pass the code type to the matching, then combine the primitives at willing:

```
char(Type, C) --> [C], { code_type(C, Type) }.

letter(L) --> char(alpha, L).
digit(D) --> char(digit, D).
lower_or_num(C) --> char(lower, C) | digit(C).
...
```

a possibility, to skip over unwanted chars (only newline or single quotes)

```
string_literal(S) --> "\"", string_inner(S).

string_inner([]) --> "\"".
string_inner(Cs) --> [C],
    { ( C == 0'\n ; C == 0'' ) -> Cs = Rs ; Cs = [C|Rs] },
    string_inner(Rs).
```

*edit*

> prevent it from matching strings that contain double quotes

the construct `if -> then ; else` fails if we omit the `else` branch, and the `if` is false, so an attempt could be:

```
...
{ ( C == 0'\n ; C == 0'' ) -> Cs = Rs ; C \== 0'" -> Cs = [C|Rs] },
...
```

Comment: Would it be possible to exclude quotes and newlines from the string literal, while allowing every other type of character?

Comment: of course, but what you want to do when quotes and/or newlines *are* found ? throw an exception or skip them ?

Comment: There's still another problem with this DCG. How can I prevent it from matching strings that contain double quotes without escape characters, such as `"hello" string"`?

Comment: I think there is a conceptual problem to solve *before* to dig into details: since double quotes are delimiters, the syntax become ambiguous. But ignoring this, see my edit.

Comment: In most programming languages, string literals are able to contain quotation marks preceded by backslash characters, like `\"` or `'\'`. The implementation above does not parse these strings correctly.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: actually, it's a nice exercise left to you to extend the DCG - to your heart. It's *very* plain applied Prolog.